# Print SSRS Report Programatically SharePoint Integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have an application that programmatically prints a SSRS report using Reporting Services Web service.

The application works fine when I print the reports to my local test server. Reporting services is configured in native mode. I'm now trying to use this application on a different server, the report is in SharePoint and Reporting services is configured to integrated mode.

I'm struggling with my report path for the print command on my application, the report path is -

```
http://SERVERNAME/ReportFolder/ReportName
```

When I try print I get this error.

```
<ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsItemNotFound</ErrorCode>
```

I've tested the report URL in internet explorer and that is working correctly but when I try send this URL to the print command in the application I get the error.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Hi Robbert, Here's the error.

Comment: <ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsItemNotFound</ErrorCode><HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus><Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">